# ajax remembering page: # vs?

Tags: jquery, ajax

im trying to use jquery bbq for remembering page with ajax.

but i wonder, why should i use # values and not ? values for remembering pages eg.

```
?country=1&region=2
```

then get the values with $_GET and display the appropiate info

vs

```
#country=1&region=2
```

cause the latter one i cannot get it with php right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because

```
#country=1&region=2
```

is bad URL syntax.
This is correct:

```
?country=1&region=2
```

and this is also correct:

```
?country=1&region=2#bookmarkname
```

Note, that # values must go AFTER ?-& values. This rule is not from PHP or jQuery, this is basic URL syntax.

P.S. String after # **is not sent to web server** (and PHP can't get it), so you HAVE to use valid syntax.

Comment: but people say that the string after # is not sent to web server

Comment: Then you HAVE to use valid syntax (?country=1&region=2).

Comment: so u mean i can get it by url?q=hello#country=1&region=2?
but not by url#country=1&region=2?

Comment: With "url?q=hello#country=1&region=2" PHP will get only "q=hello", and with "url#country=1&region=2" will get nothing.

Comment: im so confused.. u said "you still CAN get values from "#country=1&region=2" in PHP".

Comment: (I edited my answer) No you can't. This was my mistake, i forgot that string after # is not sent to web server. So you have to use valid syntax only.